# Why is this RegEx not matching this variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

Noob question here, basically what I want to do is to capture an url from an array of html copypastes

```
   var images = document.querySelectorAll('div.uiScaledImageContainer img')
   imageSelector = /(?:http.*(?="))/

   for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
console.log((imageSelector.exec(images))[i]);
}
```

I don't know if this is the best method to achieve this task, I've been learning how to code for less than a month and this is the way I came up with what I've learnt so far.

The RegEx matches the url when I paste the array into a RegEx checker; Yet when I manually input the var and the RegEx to the console it will return a false when .test and obviously a null when .exec .
And I'm left here scratching my head wondering what i did wrong.

```
>images
[
<img class="scaledImageFitHeight img" src="https://scontent-dfw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p160x160/12734050_927062960744742_7453187646865179877_n.jpg?oh=8be38f653466ef122bab606b11f6a87c&amp;oe=57ED6259" style="left:-85px;" alt="Te Queremos Escuchar's photo." width="423" height="157">
,
<img class="scaledImageFitHeight img" src="https://scontent-dfw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p296x100/13442267_1033303953373035_4117048021887988380_n.jpg?oh=ec9b7dd3f8daabc26d66d32d393437a8&amp;oe=57F1715B" style="left:0px;" alt="Academia de Cultura Asiática Ninshi's photo." width="296" height="394">
,
]
>imageSelector
 /(?:html.*?(?=")/
>imageSelector.test(images)
false
```

Comment: The result of selecting DOM elements isn't a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the test on `images` (`imageSelector.exec(images)`) but you want to do the test on `images[i]`.

Beside that `images` is a list of `Node` elements and a Node is not a string.

If you pass a non string object to `exec` then it will be converted to string. If the object has a `toString` method then this one will be used. So if you do `imageSelector.exec(images[i])` then it would be equal to `imageSelector.exec(images[i].toString())`. `toString` on a image will result in something like `[object HTMLImageElement]`.

If you want apply the RegExp on the whole html of the image then you need to use `outerHTML`: `imageSelector.exec(images[i].outerHTML)`

But to get the  `src` of the image you should use `images[i].getAttribute('src')` ([MDN: getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute))

Comment: I didn't even knew what a DOM element was, now I know how to turn them into a string and also how to get the outerHTML. And i learnt that .exec turns non string objects into strings.
Thanks a lot